# Deleting duplicate entries from CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv with 2 columns:

```
a,x
a,y
a,z
b,1
b,2
b,3
b,4
c,5
c,6
c,7
c,8
```

I'd like to loop through only look at the 1st column and only show 2 entries for each value in the first column. I don't care what values get kept or deleted for the second column, i just want 2 entries of each different option for the first column.

Output would look something like this:

```
a,x
a,y
b,1
b,2
c,5
c,6
```

I'm familiar with csv module(how to read/write/replace), but am having a hard time finding resources that explain how to compare one row with another. I think that is where I'm stuck on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a dictionary to combat this problem, maybe something along the lines of the following:

```
dict = {}

rows = [['a', 'x'], ['a', 'y'], ['a', 'z'], ['b', 1], ['b', 2], ['b', 3], ['b', 4], ['c', 5], ['c', 6], ['c', 7], ['c', 8]]

for row in rows:
    if row[0] not in dict.keys():
        dict[row[0]] = []

    if len(dict[row[0]]) == 2:
        continue

    dict[row[0]].append(row[1])

print(dict)
```

Output:

```
>> {'a': ['x', 'y'], 'b': [1, 2], 'c': [5, 6]}
```

Comment: to expand on this for anyone who finds this, i also have a seperate script that is already written to do something with the output data so i would prefer to keep that in csv format. To do that, the following worked:

CSV ="\n".join([k+','+",".join(v) for k,v in dict.items()])

Answer (score 0):

So, here's an idea, based on Jacob's:

Create two dicts, `first` and `second`

For each line in the CSV:

- if the key is in `second`, skip, else
- if the key is not in `first` put it there
- if the key is in `first`, and the value is not the line you are looing at, add the key to `second`

At the end you'll have two dictionaries with a value each as you wanted
You could generalize it to keeping N values by creating a list of dictionaries and use as many as you'd need

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with `itertools.groupby`

```
import itertools
with open("test.csv", "r") as stuff:
    data = stuff.readlines()


out = []
for k,dat in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    twoVals = list(dat)[:2]
    out.append(twoVals)

print out
```

For cases where there are less than two values

```
import itertools
with open("test.csv", "r") as stuff:
    data = stuff.readlines()


out = []
for k,dat in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    dat = list(dat)
    try:    
        vals = dat[:2]
    except IndexError:
        vals = list(dat)
    out.append(vals)

print out
```

I tested this out on:

```
a,x
a,y
a,z
b,1
b,2
b,3
b,4
c,5
c,6
c,7
c,8
z,1
```

Comment: True, and in that case you would need a `try` and `except` statement. I'll update this.